# Where to store Document Templates in Word 2013?

Tags: microsoft-word-2013, templates

I'm working on Windows 8.1 with Word 2013. I created a Template from an existing document in Word. I placed the template in `C:\Users\<me>\App Data\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates`. I open Word and attempted to create a document based on the Template. But I can't because the template is not available. Its not available on the "New Document" screen. And searching for it from within Word returns 0 results.

*File → Options → Advanced* no longer lists template locations. This new interface ***really*** sucks. Microsoft has ruined nearly every one of its programs with this cursed tablet interface.

Where do I store templates in Word 2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Office 2013 `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Templates` is used to store templates from Office.com.

The default location for personal, customized templates is now at: `My Documents\Custom Office Templates`.

Comment: an answer here: http://superuser.com/questions/653511/applying-template-to-word-2013-document/1006093#1006093